Block Reddit Homepage But Allow Subreddits
I want to block the Reddit homepage but allow subreddits. I think the simplest way to achieve this is using a regular expression. For example:
ALLOW https://reddit.com/r/*
DENY https://reddit.com/*

I'm doing this to allow myself to use Reddit for research purposes but stop myself from endlessly scrolling.
I'm open to spending some money on a solution for this - I'm generally interested in granular internet access control. Less than USD $300 would be ideal.

https://pi-hole.net/ and https://getcoldturkey.com/

Welcome Dali!  You can accomplish this with Redirector.  I sadly don't have enough free time to create the Redirector rule for you right at this moment, but it's not too hard.  If you make a donation to a good charity, I'll try to make it a priority, but I'm overwhelmed with projects at the moment.  Here is the link to Redirector for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/redirector/

For which browsers? All?
